# UserControl changing Visibility for Rectangles with ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a ComboBox in UserControl with 4 choices that change the visibility of 4 Rectangles which are in the MainWindow.

I managed to make it work while the Combobox is in the MainWindow, but when i move it to the UserControl it doesn´t work anymore

I tried to put in UserControl
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
and put in front

`mw.blau_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` -> Here i do get StackOverFlow error

This is the XAML for the Rectangles in the MainWindow:

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="blau_rec" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="Aqua"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Blue"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="orange_rec" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="Orange"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="OrangeRed"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="grey_rec" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="#8E8E8E"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#585858"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="light_rec" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="#D5D5D5"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#BEBEBE"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

This is the Code in UserControl.cs

```
    private void cbx_colorChanger_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var farbe1 = cbx_colorChanger.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (farbe1.Content.ToString() == "Blau")
        {
            blau_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            blau_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        var farbe2 = cbx_colorChanger.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (farbe2.Content.ToString() == "Orange")
        {
            orange_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            orange_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        var farbe3 = cbx_colorChanger.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (farbe3.Content.ToString() == "Grau")
        {
            grey_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            grey_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        var farbe4 = cbx_colorChanger.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (farbe4.Content.ToString() == "Hell")
        {
            light_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            light_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

and this is the ComboBox in UserControl:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbx_colorChanger" Width="200" Height="25" SelectionChanged="cbx_colorChanger_SelectionChanged" >
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cbx_blau_rec" Content="Blau"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cbx_orange_rec" Content="Orange"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cbx_grey_rec" Content="Grau"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cbx_light_rec" Content="Hell"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Please i need some help getting along with this, thank you!

Comment: A UserControl should never directly access the main (or any other) Window. It should instead expose four bindable properties (i.e. dependency properties), to which the Visibility properties of the Rectangles could be bound. Or better, expose a single property, and bind the Visibilities with a Binding Converter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a static instance of MainWindow and set it equal to this in the constructor like so:

```
public static MainWindow thisWindow;


public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        thisWindow = this;
    }
```

Now you can access your MainWindow from anywhere:

```
MainWindow.thisWindow.blau_rec.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Besides that this shows bad practice, it is entirely redundant, because you can already access the MainWindow instance by `(MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow`.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the tip, is there a way to access other Pages than the MainWindow like this?

Comment: Maybe, but a control should never directly access other elements.